# WSO2 API-M v4.1.0: 404 with log message STATUS = Message dispatched to the main sequence. Invalid URL., RESOURCE = , HEALTH CHECK URL

Tags: wso2

I was able to create and publish APIs on my dev WSO2 installation based on H2 DB. Unfortunately started from the fifth APIs (the first four still working very well) I have this error.

If I'm calling the API from Postman I receive

{
"code": 404,
"type": "Status report",
"message": "Not Found",
"description": "The requested resource is not available."
}

Into the logs I see

INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - STATUS = Message dispatched to the main sequence. Invalid URL., RESOURCE = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, HEALTH CHECK URL = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Any help will appriciate.

API-M version 4.1.0

Regards,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WSO2 API Manager periodic error on console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40187400/wso2-api-manager-periodic-error-on-console)